# How automatize adding a product in stripe

Tags: django, django-views, stripe-payments

i'm trying to add stripe at my django project and i need to put a custom proce every time i want to buy something. Im doing a house rental type of site so i could do 2 things:
1- Automatize the proccess, creating a script that would create a product with the exact proze of the shopping cart
2-Instead of creating a product with the price of the shopping cart, create a product everytime y add a new house to the database and then buying it all in stripe
Personally i would prefer the first one but i dont know if its possible. Someone could help with this?

```
checkout_session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
      payment_method_types = ['card'],
      line_items = [{
      'price': total_post_gestion*100,
      'quantity': 1,}]
```

#This is what i have at the moment but stripe tells me i need to have a price tagged to a product and doesen't let me put an integer

Answer (score 0):

If you need custom price each time then you can use [price_data](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-line_items-price_data) parameter instead of using `price` in. the `line_items`

This allows you to create inline price objects each time. Example [here](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=checkout#redirect-customers)

Comment: Thank you so so so much, the payment went through without problems